# Recortar Imagen seleccionada de la Galería

Tags: java, android

Lo que realizo en mi código es lo siguiente:

Selecciono una imagen de la galería, la redimensiono a *150x150*, creo un *.png* en mi dispositivo y guardo la ruta en mi `Sqlite`, hasta ahí todo bien. Pero quiero cambiar algo, quiero poder recortar la imagen (desde la opción *Recortar* de la Galería) antes de crear el *.png*, me explico:

Seleccionar una imagen de la Galería > Poder recortar la imagen en *150x150* (pero desde la opción *Recortar* de la Galería, muestro abajo un ejemplo) > Guardar el *.png* en mi dispositivo > ... ya todo esto creo que no habría que modificarlo.

Quiero cambiar esto porque al redimensionar la imagen completa en *150x150* se ve deformada y si puedo *recortar* la imagen desde la Galería en esas medidas no habría problemas.

Ejemplo de lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como selecciono la imagen de la Galería y guardo un *.png* en 150x150

`clase`:

```
// Metodo que abre la galeria
private void ventanaImagen() {
    try {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Seleccionar de la galería" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Seleccionar una foto");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            //Define path donde sera guardada una nueva imagen con medidas 150x150px
            File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("Download");
            File file;
            if(ruta_imagen.isEmpty()) { //No contiene imagen
                Log.e(TAG, "NO contiene imagen, crea imagen.");
                file = new File(dir, "profile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, "Contiene imagen, path " + ruta_imagen);
                file = new File(ruta_imagen);
            }
            if (!file.exists()) { //Si archivo no existe.
                try {
                    file.createNewFile(); //Procede a crearlo.
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult() " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (bitmap != null) {
                //Redimensiona imagen.
                Bitmap bitmapout = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 150, 150, false);
                FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmapout.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
                //Muestra imagen con nuevas medidas en ImageView.
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenPersona);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapout);
                //Obtengo la ruta de la imagen creada en el dispositivo.
                Log.i(TAG, "Ruta imagen en archivo : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                ruta_imagen = file.getAbsolutePath();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error obteniendo imagen", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: UserNameYo, te recomendaría probar la library que comenta @mmsergi y comentar resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He utilizado esta librería [Android-Crop](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) y realiza a la perfección lo que necesitaba. Solucionado!

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sin el uso de libraries, sería obtener la medida del bitmap y obtener una proporcional definiendo un porcentaje

```
private static int FACTOR = 5; //5%
```

de esta forma calcularía un tamaño proporcional al original:

```
                int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
                int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

                int bitmapWidthResized = (FACTOR * bitmapWidth)/100;
                int bitmapHeightResized = (FACTOR * bitmapHeight)/100;
                Log.i(TAG, "medidas originales, width : " + bitmapWidth + " ,height : " + bitmapHeight);
                Log.i(TAG, "nuevas medidas, width : " + bitmapWidthResized + " ,height : " + bitmapHeightResized);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una librería externa, como por ejemplo [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper).